# traefik forward request if ip address not on ip whitelist

Tags: traefik

We currently use [Traefik IPWhiteList middleware](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/ipwhitelist/) to restrict the access to our application. If the Ip address is not on the whitelist, Traefik sends back a 403 forbidden. The user should now be redirected to another page. unfortunately I can't find a way to set this up. is there a possibility that I have missed or is this really not possible with Traefik?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create both Middlewares [errors](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/errorpages/) and [ipwhitelist](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/ipwhitelist/), as you can see in the image down below from line 62:

[image]

After, you have to link the Middlewares to your service, as you can see on line 108:

[image]

You must link the error Middlewares first

Then, create the endpoint which will return the response, for instance:

[image]

And you will receive the following response

[image]

Comment: The IP whitelist already works without any problems. We do want to redirect the user to another page instead of returning the 403 forbidden. I tried it with the ErrorPage middleware but I had no success yet.

Comment: oh sorry, I misunderstood what you want. I will check how to do that

Comment: Hi, I have updated my answer, so you can check it if you continue stuck on that

Comment: It actually seems to work that way. The only problem was that I tried to redirect it to another subdomain where my problem currently is. Do you have any idea how to redirect the request from example.com to login.example.com instead of showing the forbidden page?